# Max4080 REF pins

Tags: current-measurement, module

Bought the Max4080 module and as usual I read the datasheet after purchasing it. In the [datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX4080-MAX4081.pdf) pin 6 and 7 are NC but on the module those two pins are connected as F1B and F1A:

[image]

What F1B and F1A pins is for?

Max4080 **SASA** means it has gain of 60?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These pins are only used for the MAX4081. They used the same dev board for MAX 4080/4081. If you work with the MAX4080 don't care about these two pins.

Yes, MAX4080 SASA has a gain of 60 in an SO8 package.